# MongoDB java driver create Document with $in filter

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java

I think this should be easy to do, but I just couldn't figure it out.
What I'm trying to achieve is this query

```
{inbox:{$in:["main","fun-inbox"]} ,status:"Open"}
```

I managed to make it work like this

```
     Bson q = Filters
            .and(Filters
                    .in("inbox", inboxes),
                Filters
                    .eq("status", statusID));
```

but is not the same thing because I used the `$and` operator

Can this be done using `Document` ?

Here is what I've tried and I know is wrong the way I define it, but I'll put the example just to better understand what I'm trying to achieve

```
     Document q1 = new Document()
             .append("inbox", Filters.in("inbox", inboxes))
             .append("status", statusID);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have is correct and it is **not** explicitly $anded.

Java Mongo driver behind the scene figures out when to $and and when to not.

For example

Without `$and`

```
Bson bson = Filters.and(Filters.in("inbox", inboxes), Filters.eq("status", status));

BsonDocument bsonDocument = bson.toBsonDocument(BsonDocument.class, MongoClient.getDefaultCodecRegistry());

System.out.print(bsonDocument.toString()); //{ "inbox" : { "$in" : inboxes }, "status" : status }
```

With `$and`

```
Bson bson = Filters.and(Filters.in("inbox", inboxes), Filters.eq("inbox", inbox));

BsonDocument bsonDocument = bson.toBsonDocument(BsonDocument.class, MongoClient.getDefaultCodecRegistry());

System.out.print(bsonDocument.toString()); //{ "$and" : [{ "inbox" : { "$in" : inboxes } }, { "inbox" : inbox }] }
```

Comment: Is it me or both examples are identical and return the same result without $and ?

Comment: Mongo queries are implicity and'ed except in [few](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/#op._S_and) situations. Yes they are both same without $and because explicitly $and ing is not needed in both cases and I've just shown that for demonstration.

Comment: I'm talking about the second code "With $and" . It's the same code as the first one "Without $and"

Comment: oh okay. No its not. Note the difference the inbox field is now checked for two criteria i.e. output documents where inbox is in passed inboxes list `and` also inbox equal to specific inbox. This can also be reduced to `{ "inbox" : { "$in" : inboxes, $eq: inbox }}` without $and

Answer (score 2):

Converted your query to java code to return Iterable Document type

```
FindIterable<Document> iterable = database.getCollection("mails").find(new Document("inbox", new Document("$in", inValues)).append("status", "open"));
```

and `inValues` is an `ArrayList` as

```
ArrayList<String> inValues = new ArrayList<String> ();
inValues.add("main");
inValues.add("fun-inbox");
```